# I want to host my vimrc on a publicly accessible server

Tags: linux, ftp

I've tried a couple of things so far and have not managed to achieve my objective so I've decided it's time to ask for some help...

Here's my situation. I have may different systems/servers I regularly need to login to in order to do my work.

Each time I change server, I run vim to start doing some work, and I haven't setup/copied my vimrc to that server yet.

I think it would be really useful if I could just login to a new system and run a command that gets my vimrc file from a publicly accessible server.

Here's what I've done so far:

I've setup a linux server, and I know the ip address of it. (At the moment it's just on my local machine.)

I've put my vimrc on the server. (Location tbc)

Here's where I start guessing.

I need some kind of service running on the server which can be connected to, and some kind of client which I can run to connect to the server and get the file.

I thought perhaps something like ftp would be a good solution? But I'm not sure. It seems to have some problems.

- FTP sends passwords without encryption. That's not a problem if I use an anonymous login, without a password, but I haven't found any way to *disable* user/password logins to the ftp service I installed. That would be something I would want to do for security reasons, in case I accidentally forget one day and send my password in plain text over the internet. Which would be pretty dumb but something that might happen given a lack of coffee one day.
- I can't figure out a way of using FTP on the client side to download the file I want in a 1 line bash command. So far I can run `ftp <ip>` on my client and enter a kind of ftp shell, but that's not what I want to be doing.

Am I using the wrong tool for the job here?

Server side I am using `proftp` (`proftpd`). Client side I am using `ftp` (`sudo apt install ftp` on Debian 9)

I want to be able to do something along the lines of

```
ssh user@workserver
<login>
get from_mypublicfileserver:/srv/ftp/myvimrc ~/.vimrc
```

where `get` is `ftp` or something else - I don't know what kind of command should go here.

`workserver` is some random server I am logging into for the day to work on

`from_mypublicfileserver` is just a placeholder for 192.168.XXX.XXX (or later some public IP address where I host whatever services and files I want to be able to download from anywhere, and be publicly accessible)

As an extension perhaps it would be a good idea to be able to host some stuff which is not public but user/pass protected. Obviously ftp is the wrong thing to be using here. I can post this as a separate question if necessary.

## Edits

I've made some progress in that apparently `curl` can be used to download a single file from a bash script

For example

```
curl ftp://192.168.XXX.XXX/test.txt > test.txt
```

Comment: You could also download the file over HTTP from a webserver. You could even host the thing as a GitHub Snippet... Take a look at how RVM is installed, it literally downloads a bash script and pipes it into a shell for execution (http://rvm.io/)

Comment: Have you looked in to rsync yet? https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

Answer (score 2):

SCP (secure copy) is probably what you want:

```
scp user@from_mypublicfileserver:/srv/myfiles/myvimrc ~/.vimrc
```

If you are able to SSH into a machine, then you are also able to SCP a file to/from it.

Comment: This solution requires a password however - I guess that answers the final part of the question but unless ssh keys are installed (another additional step) then I don't think this would work well as part of a bash script (although I didn't mention that in the question originally). It's a pretty simple solution though I should have thought about using this

Comment: @user3728501 Yes, if you want to automate it, you've got to either use keys or use the sshpass command (with all the security implications that entails). If you don't want to do that, you're probably better off with http, ftp or tftp.

Answer (score 0):

I maintain my dotfiles inside a git (bare) repository. To setup my .bashrc .vimrc .profile etc. a simple `git clone ...` is sufficient. See this [article](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/dotfiles) for more details. You should also have a look at [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) and [Puppet](https://puppet.com/). Today there is no more need to log into a server and do stuff manually.